# Consolidating data under one month in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query for a class, and I'm having a bit of trouble with it. I need the query to pull up all of the students who registered in the month of February. I have a working query now, but it's not outputting what I need. Here's what I have so far...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) "February_Registration", enroll_date
FROM enrollment 
WHERE enroll_date LIKE '%FEB%'
GROUP BY enroll_date ;
```

This is the output I'm getting from this query...

```
February_registration | enroll_date
...................................
14 | 02-FEB-07
36 | 01-FEB-07
22 | 10-FEB-07
26 | 16-FEB-07
20 | 07-FEB-07
24 | 11-FEB-07
```

What I need it to do is to add up all those numbers under a single "February" row like this...

```
February_Registration | enroll_date
142 | February
```

What am I missing, and what do I need to do to make it work. Please explain yourself before posting code, I want to actually learn the material, and it's extremely difficult to do that if I have to sit there and figure out code that I've never seen before. It's not helpful, and I would like a good explanation along with any code suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `GROUP BY`, if you just want the total.

And the, *never* use `LIKE` on a date column.  `LIKE` takes string arguments, so the date column is converted to a string, using various setting in the database (that most people do not usually fiddle with).

Here is an alternative:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as February_Registration,
       'February' as enroll_date  -- I'm not exactly sure why this is needed
FROM enrollment 
WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM enroll_date) = 2;
```

Or, you could express this as:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(enroll_date, 'MON') = 'FEB'
```

Note that the double quotes are not needed.

Now, in general, one doesn't care about "February".  One cares about February in a given year.  If that is the case, the query is best written as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as February_Registration
FROM enrollment 
WHERE enroll_date >= DATE '2016-02-01' AND
      enroll_date < DATE '2016-03-01';
```

By avoiding function calls on `enroll_date`, you give the optimizer more opportunities to tune the query.

Comment: That will give you the amount of records, not the amount of students registered. You should use SUM() instead of COUNT().

Comment: @walen . . . I don't understand the comment at all.  The OP's original query uses `count()`.  Presumably, `enrollment` has one row per student to be counted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Whoops! You're right, I mistook OP's COUNT query results for the original rows in the DB. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM( February_Registration ) AS February_Registration,
       CASE WHEN EXTRACT( MONTH FROM enroll_date ) = '02' 
            THEN 'February' END AS enroll_date
  FROM enrollment
GROUP BY enroll_date;
```

Comment: Would this work? I think the `EXTRACT` function would return a number and not a string.

Comment: Changed 'FEB' to 02